# Event when shape drawing is complete?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps to display a large number of shapes (markers, lines, polygons). We have thousands of shapes and performance is pretty good as we stream that data onto the map. However, right now we have no reliable way to let the user know that all drawing has been completed. We know when we sent all data to the map, but there is some latency (particularly with Polygons) that increases with the amount of data sent, sometimes more than a few seconds before all the drawing on the canvas is complete. During that time, the map is essentially locked up as drawing commences.

None of this is terrible, but we would like to display a visual indication that loading/drawing is in progress so the user has an indication of what is going on. Is there an event that is raised once the map has completed drawing all shapes (similar to idle, however, it appears that idle does not take drawing operations into consideration).

Comment: How is the shape data being passed to the map? Are the shapes stored in an array? If so, you could display the loading bar by default, then get the length of the array, and increment a counter. Once the counter has reached the last item in the array (i.e, the length of the array), then you can remove the loader from the screen.

Comment: Yes, it is an array, but your suggestion won't work, sadly. Essentially, the data is passed to google via SetEntities (you pass in the entire array) and the method pretty much returns immediately as this only adds the drawing workload to a work queue. 

The actual drawing is executed after google performs additional internal processing. Once the drawing starts executing, it is blocking the UI thread as canvas drawing runs synchronously. Canvas is actually pretty fast, but google seems to do some processing between the actual drawing ops, slowing things down.

Comment: As an aside, I tried adding a timeout immediately after the SetEntities, in the hope that this would be blocked until drawing operations are complete, but unfortunately this is not the case. I have experimented with the timing of the timeout, thus far without success...